# Add svg attributes in diagrams

Tags: haskell, diagram, haskell-diagrams

I would like to add tooltips (or hovering behavior) on SVG diagrams generated by `diagrams`.

Is there a way to add custom properties to a diagram , or worst comes to the worst be able to set and id to things, so they can be referred to in Javascript.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but are there any news on this? It is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The question is slightly misleading because the title property that gives tooltips on SVGs in browsers is not an attribute, but an element of its own. You add tooltips, that is SVG titles, with the method svgTitle in Diagrams.Backend.SVG.

The same module also contains methods svgID and svgClass to add these attributes to allow external javascript to find specific SVG elements.

Answer (score 0):

I kept googling, and havn't tried it yet, but I found [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-svg-1.3.1.3/docs/Diagrams-Backend-SVG-Attributes.html). It seems to exist to exactly satisfy your need.

It is SVG backend only.

Comment: It looks like it has been removed in version 1.4 which is probably why I never saw it. However it seems to have been reintroduced in v 1.4.3 (Dec 2019).